# How to send a date in a url

Tags: python, django, url, filter

I have this URL

```
url(r'^expedienteBusqueda/(?P<credencial>\w+)/(?P<fecha>\d{4})$','ExpMedico.views.Expediente_Detalle', name='consultaexpediente'),
```

I'm sending a credential of a client and the date when the client had a appointment, I need to make a search with this 2 parameters, but, when I click on the search botton I get this error.

```
Reverse for 'consultaexpediente' with arguments '(u'12335t', datetime.date(2013, 8, 21))' and keyword arguments '{}' not found.
```

It works fine when I only send the credential, but the problem is when I add the date.

view.py

```
@login_required(login_url='/InicieSesion')
def Expediente_Detalle(request, credencial,fecha):
    formulario = get_object_or_404(ExpedienteConsultaInicial, credencial_consultainicial=credencial and ExpedienteConsultaInicial, fecha_atencion_18=fecha )
    detalle = ConsultasSubsecuentes.objects.filter(Consultasbc_credencial=credencial )
    return render(request, 'ExpedienteDetalle.html', {'formulario': formulario, 'detalle':detalle})
```

models.py

```
class ExpedienteConsultaInicial(models.Model):
     credencial_consultainicial = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=True, blank=True)
     fecha_atencion_18 = models.DateField(auto_now=True, null=True, blank=True)
```

Template.html

```
<td><a href="{% url consultaexpediente  post.credencial_consultainicial, post.fecha_atencion_18%}" class="btn">Ver Expediente</a></td>
```

Comment: Your fecha only expects four digits but you are sending it a whole date.  You need to format the date to match the url's \d{4} or vice-versa.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `url` tag is passing positional arguments, but your url is expecting keyword arguments, so you need to update your template:

```
{% url 'consultaexpediente'
        credencial=post.credencial_consultainicial,
        fecha=post.fecha_atencion_18 %}
```

The second problem is you are passing in a datetime object, when you really need to pass in a date. To fix that, first adjust your URL expression:

```
r'^expedienteBusqueda/(?P<credencial>\w+)/(?P<fecha>\d{8})$'
```

Now you need to pass the date. I have set the url pattern to expect 8 digits, so your date should be 20130913 (for today). This should be fixed in your URL tag:

```
   {% url 'consultaexpediente'
        credencial=post.credencial_consultainicial,
        fecha=post.fecha_atencion_18|date:"Ymd" %}
```

Now that the date is being passed in correctly, we need to fix your view code:

```
@login_required(login_url='/InicieSesion')
def Expediente_Detalle(request, credencial, fecha):
    date_for_search = datetime.datetime.strptime(fecha, '%Y%m%d').date()
    formulario = get_object_or_404(ExpedienteConsultaInicial,
                 credencial_consultainicial=credencial,
                 fecha_atencion_18=date_for_search)
    detalle = formulario.consultascubsecuentes_set.all()
    return render(request,
                  'ExpedienteDetalle.html',
                  {'formulario': formulario, 'detalle':detalle})
```